# Como fazer aparecer a notificação para permitir o Flash Player?

Tags: html

Tenho um site em PHP, e em alguns diretórios preciso que o usuário esteja com o *Flash Player* habilitado, então busco fazer algo [como isto](https://prnt.sc/h3omna).

Qualquer lugar que eu clique no campo da imagem e do botão faz com que apareça a notificação para permitir o *Flash Player*. Como fazer isso?

Comment: É um servidor de jogo em flash, basicamente redireciona para a página e  jogo é executado, mas com o bloqueio do flash o site fica com tela preta até que seja habilitado, gostaria de fazer como no printscreen, mostrar ao usuário a notificação para Permitir o Flash depois de clicar num determinado botão  que apareceria caso o seu flash estivesse desabilitado

Comment: exemplo prático: https://jsfiddle.net/wtzbbhLb/show/

Comment: Não é meu o site, é de um usuário do fórum, e não consegui reproduzi-lo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, basicamente funciona assim como no exemplo que você citou:

```
<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Clique aqui para habilitar o Flash</a>
```

Ao clicar, caso a permissão padrão seja perguntar, vai aparecer uma mensagem perguntando se ele deseja habilitar o *Flash Player*.

Caso a permissão padrão seja bloquear, vai aparecer uma ícone no canto direito do navegador informando que um plugin foi bloqueado.

Caso já esteja permitido, vai abrir o site do *Flash Player* para download do *plugin*.

Talvez você não esteja conseguindo reproduzir esse efeito pois sua permissão padrão já é para permitir ou bloquear. Experimente trocar para a permissão de perguntar, então o exemplo irá funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito! Eu não tinha me atentado que estava já permitido, obrigado pelo toque e desculpa a ignorância!